# Выход из блока div ckeditor

Tags: ckeditor

Здравствуйте. Если я вставляю div, то весь текст идет только в нем, нажимаю enter, и это всего лишь увеличивает высоту блока. Как мне выйти из этого блока и дальше писать текст?

Comment: все, разобрался

Comment: @thedude, По возможности публикуйте ответы на форуме, они могут помочь многим в будущем.

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно поправить следующую строчку в `config.js`:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function (config) {
    // ...
    config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_DIV;
    // ...
}
```

Учтите, что это плохая практика.